# Punctuation in LanguagueTool rules

Tags: regex, xml, spell-checking, languagetool

I cannot figure our how to write rules in which tokens involve a combination of words and punctuation.

**How should I handle punctuation in `LanguageTool` rules?**

I have looked online and tried a couple of things to no avail.

For instance, both 1)

```
<rule id="THAT_AND_THAN_DOT" name="that and than dot">
<pattern>
<token>that</token> 
<token regexp="yes"> 
another.|
himself.|
herself.|
itself.</token>
</pattern>
<message>Did you mean <suggestion>than \2.</suggestion>?</message>
<example correction='than another.'>Yes, better <marker>than another. </marker></example>
</rule>
```

2)

```
<rule id="THAT_AND_THAN_DOT" name="that and than dot">
<pattern>
<token>that</token> 
<token regexp="yes"> 
another|
himself|
herself|
itself</token>
<token regexp="yes">
[.]</token> 
</pattern>
<message>Did you mean <suggestion>than \2.</suggestion>?</message>
<example correction='than another.'>Yes, better <marker>than another. </marker></example>
</rule>
```

and 3)

```
<rule id="THAT_AND_THAN_DOT" name="that and than dot">
<pattern>
<token>that</token> 
<token regexp="yes"> 
another|
himself|
herself|
itself</token>
<token regexp="yes">
[:punct:]</token> 
</pattern>
<message>Did you mean <suggestion>than \2.</suggestion>?</message>
<example correction='than another.'>Yes, better <marker>than another. </marker></example>
</rule>
```

failed. On the other hand

```
<rule id="THAT_AND_THAN_DOT" name="that and than dot">
    <pattern>
    <token>that</token> 
    <token regexp="yes"> 
    another|
    himself|
    herself|
    itself</token>
    </pattern>
    <message>Did you mean <suggestion>than \2.</suggestion>?</message>
    <example correction='than another.'>Yes, better <marker>than another. </marker></example>
    </rule>
```

works, albeit without accounting for the dot, which I would like to do.

**Note :** I am using `LanguageTool` inside `Texstudio`.

Comment: Have you tried `<token regexp="yes">(?:another|himself|herself|itself)[.]</token>`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I just tried it as part of `<rule id="THAT_AND_THAN_DOT" name="that and than dot">
  <pattern>
  <token>that</token> 
  <token regexp="yes">(?:another|himself|herself|itself)[.]</token>
  </pattern>
  <message>Did you mean <suggestion>than \2</suggestion>?</message>
  <example correction='than another.'>Yes, <marker>than another.</marker></example>
 </rule>` to no avail. I don't think it should matter but just in case : I am using `LanguageTool` inside `Texstudio`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in 2) almost works, only that you have a token `that` in the pattern but `than` in your example sentence, so it will never match, independent of the punctuation. In general, punctuation gets its own token so it needs to have its own token in the pattern, too. You can test your rules with http://community.languagetool.org/ruleEditor/expert, it will also show a message with the applied tokenization in case of problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure I am following you. Do you mean there is a `that` in `<example correction='than another.'>Yes, <marker>than another. </marker></example>`? What is the difference between the example sentence in 2) (that does not work) and the one in 4) (that works)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "works", but number 4) does not work when pasted into http://community.languagetool.org/ruleEditor/expert. The example sentence contains "than another" but the pattern cannot match as is contains the token "that". I suggest you use that online form so we have the same idea of "works" and "fails".

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the way <example> work. By "4) works" I meant that -- at least on my side using `LanguageTool` via `Texstudio` -- 4) was enough for `LanguageTool` to catch instances of "that another" and proposed the correction "than another".